# how to access an element in an html string that has not been added to the DOM tree yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm loading an HTML template file, which contains templates that I'm using throughout my application. The file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>static_listview_templates</title></head><body>
<ul id="tmp_listview_basic" class="ui-listview"></ul>
<ul id="tmp_listview_inset" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow"></ul>

<li id="tmp_listview_divider" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-[theme] ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-divider-text"></span></li>
...
</body></html>
```

The template is pulled in via `requireJS` which gives me back the HTML code as a text string.

I have converted the string into a jQuery object using `var el = $( string )` but I still can't access any of the elements (I assume because they are not in the DOM yet).

**Question**:
Is there a way in jQuery/javascript to

```
el.find('#tmp_listview_divider')   // which gives me an empty object []
```

to select an element from my template object? If so, how can I access and pull out one of the sub_templates? If not, how would I select a strubstring "by ID"? I can add a start and end identifier, but I have no idea how to regex `"from start-to-end"`

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
My HTML template:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>static_listview_templates</title></head><body><form id="tmp_listview_filter" class="ui-listview-filter ui-bar-[theme] ui-listview-filter-inset" role="search"><div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-icon-searchfield ui-body-[theme]"><input placeholder="" data-type="search" class="ui-input-text ui-body-[theme]"><a title="" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-x ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-notext ui-input-clear-hidden" href="#" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="[theme]" data-mini="false">><span class="ui-btn-text"></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a></div></form><ul id="tmp_listview_basic" class="ui-listview"></ul><ul id="tmp_listview_inset" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow"></ul><li id="tmp_listview_divider" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-[theme] ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-divider-text"></span></li><li id="tmp_listview_item" data-filtertext="[filtertext]" data-theme="c" class="ui-li ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-first-child ui-last-child ui-btn-up-[theme]"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="[link]" class="ui-link-inherit">[link_content]</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-[link-icon] ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li></body></html>
```

In my application controller I'm doing this:

```
... on pagebeforeshow ...
// pull template and language
require(['text!../tx/static_listview.html','i18n!nls/locale_search'], 

   function ( tmp_listview, lib_search ) {
        // element config JSON
        var dyn = $.parseJSON( page.find(':jqmData(template="true")').jqmData("config") );
        console.log( dyn );

        // template                    
        console.log( tmp_listview )
        var tmp = $( tmp_listview ),
            el = tmp.find('#tmp_listview_divider');

        // always []
        console.log( el )
   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `el.find()` on your document fragment once you've put the HTML string into a jQuery object as you've done, but your selector `'#tmp_listview_divider#'` looks wrong.  There should not be a trailing `#`.

If you show us the relevant piece of HTML, we could help you get the selector right.

Edit: Based on the HTML you've now added to your question, you should be able to just use this:

```
el.find('#tmp_listview_divider')
```

Comment: ah. I wanted to select by id. Too much Coldfusion variables lately... (requiring to wrap in ##)... Edited. I will add the full code. 1 sec

Comment: To select by id, just a leading `#`.  Do you have a `#` in the actual id?  If so, you will have to escape it with `\ ` which means you need `\\ ` in your javascript string declaration.

Comment: the id's in the template look fine. I can console my `tmp` object and it has all the elements in it `( ul#tmp_listview_basic, #ul...)`, but I can't access them.

Comment: If the HTML is a legal fragment of HTML, `el.find('#tmp_listview_divider')` works as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Btdxb/.

Comment: ha. Then mine must work, too. Thanks for the help and fiddle. Back to searching. I will post once I have it.

Comment: Your HTML does not work, probably because it's not a legal HTML fragment.  When I clean it up to be legal, it works.

Comment: If I remove all [] and can pass the w3c validator, it should work, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
var el = $('<div />').html(string).find('#tmp_listview_divider');
```

or:

```
var el = $(string).filter('#tmp_listview_divider');
```

But the former is probably more stable incase a template is returned wrapped in one element or something.

You have to do one of these because `.find()` gets the descendants of the matched elements, so `$(string)` will return your document fragment as `[<title>, <ul>, <ul>, <li>...]` and then `.find()` will search the descendants of title, ul, ul, li etc. for `#tmp_listview_divider` which is not what you want. You need to wrap it all in an element that you can `.find()` within first.